# gradle experimental ndk build only subset of directory

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, android-ndk, gradle-experimental

I am using gradle2.9 with the gradle-experimental-0.6.0-alpha3 plugin for android studio and I have a problem I cannot seem to solve.

This is my directory structure:

- TopDir

  - fileA.cpp
  - dirA

    - fileA1.cpp
    - fileA2.cpp

I want to compile fileA.cpp, fileA1.cpp but not fileA2.cpp

1°) I tried using selective dir includes:

```
android.sources {
    main {
        jni {
            source {
               srcDirs = ["dirA","dirA1/fileA1.cpp"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but I got the error that dirA1/fileA1.cpp is not a directory, and I can't find a way to include a file.

2°) I tried using selective dir excludes:

```
android.sources {
    main {
        jni {
            source {
               srcDirs = ["TopDir"]
               exclude "fileA2.cpp"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but that didn't work either, because exclude waits for a directory. Even using wildcards (like "exclude *A2*") doesn't seems to work.

Does anyone knows a way to do this (even if it requires including file one by one) using the new gradle experimental tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For exclude, you can use wildcards, e.g

```
exclude "**/*A2.cpp"
```